# The unclickable link: hover options in chat have thwarted my quest for knowledge

Tags: bug, chat, tooltips

*While perusing my local chat room, I espied a link in a [message](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/43749580#43749580) that I desired to visit:*

[image]

*But Lo! Whereupon I attempted to click said link, the hover options appeared and blocked my passage:*

[image]

*Woe unto me! The link is unreachable! However shall I proceed?*

*Mayhaps the interface can be improved so none shall have to suffer as I have this day.*

Comment: "Dummy" solution, but wouldn't resizing/zooming the page just squeeze the message and move said buttons away from the message they were overlaying?

Comment: Can you please link to the chat message in question?

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog: Done. Since the hover options don't appear in the transcript permalink, it's not an issue there, but still is in the chat room.

Comment: @gnostradamus in a sense you answered your question: visit the transcript and click :P

Comment: @Jenayah: That works, but having to resize your window to reach links doesn't make for a very friendly UI.

Comment: Without the rune of zoom, your progress will be long and difficult.

Comment: Mayhaps the Wand of Scrolling doth be thy friend in this dire peril?